# How is $x^3 - x^2 - 1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

My book says that this polynomial is irreducible over the said field. Clearly, the polynomial does not have root $r = 1$ since $(1)^3 -(1)^2 - 1 = -1 \not\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

However, for $r = -1$, we have $(-1)^3 - (-1)^2 - 1 = -3 \equiv 0 \mod 3$.

So wouldn't this mean that $x^3 - x^2 - 1$ is reducible since it has root $-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, it is reducible. It is $(x+1)(x^2+x-1)$.

Comment: This one is irreducible for all primes $q = 2 u^2 + uv + 4 v^2$ with $u,v$ integers. If they had written $x^3 - x - 1,$ it would have been irreducible for $3$ and all primes $p = 2 u^2 + uv + 3 v^2.$ In both, we sometimes need to take $uv < 0,$ in order to guarantee all those primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that it is a reducible polynomial, your book is incorrect. Since $-1$ is a root, by the Factor Theorem $(x-(-1))|(x^3-x^2-1)$ where the division is being considered in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. Notably, it factors into $$(x+1)(x^2+x-1)=x^3+2x^2-1\equiv x^3-x^2-1\pmod{3}$$

Comment: the given cubic is irreducible for primes $q = 2 u^2 + uv + 4 v^2.$ Just one of those things.

Comment: 2,      5,      7,     19,     41,     59,     71,     97,    101,    103,
    107,    109,    113,    157,    163,    191,    193,    211,    233,    257,
    281,    307,    311,    317,    359,    373,    397,    419,    421,    439,